# How can I get data from another page in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, checkbox

Here is Problem Details:

I have a Page which have some `checkboxes` and `checkbox` lists (is checked) and a button which to search more options.
Now I click on the button and the new page is display to searching item in that new page.
When I finish my search. I want when I click on X (exit the search page) the data is feed back to `checkbox` list.

So How can I automatically fill the data which had been searched in new search page on old page (which consists some checkbox and checkboxlists) and not change the value selected on checkboxlist and checkbox. Not change value is important for me because I have many many selected checkbox.

Please tell me how can I do that in ASP.NET.

Comment: Typically you pass data between two pages by using QueryString, Session, or cookies. In this case though, it sounds like you might be able to combine the two pages into one? Have the search functionality display as a dialog box, perhaps using Dialog from jQuery UI or ModalPopupExtender from the Ajax Control Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're useing webforms, you can look into viewstate. You can save the users selections there and retrive them to reset the state of the checkboxes.

EDIT: if your pages are physically different, viewstate will not work. Regardless, local storage is likely the best option.

You could do this with cookies and local storage as well. Local storage is probably the easiest and fastest option in my opinion. It really is quite simple to use. You can do it all through javascript.

This should get you started...
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

When the user goes back to the first page with the checkboxes, you would pull the local storage objects and run through your checkboxes to check the appropriate ones.

Comment: ViewState doesn't persist between different pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can done this by using State Management Techniques.You can use(session,cookies,query string...) which is best to you.Here are the links.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.ASPX
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492397/State-Management-in-ASP-NET-Introduction
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331962/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-State-Management
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_managing_state.htm